# Need to trim string

Tags: php

I have string:

```
[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103)
[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733)
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)Evgeniy_Kytyzov (phoenix tucson 
scottdale chandler brainburg saintrose mesa redrock events helpers ) 2018- 
12-12 23:51:54Esten_Middles (phoenix tucson scottdale chandler brainburg 
saintrose mesa redrock central events helpers ) 2018-12-12 
23:52:31Steff_Kingston
```

But i need only:

```
[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103)
[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733)
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)
```

It can be:

```
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)Evgeniy_Kytyzov (phoenix tucson 
scottdale chandler brainburg saintrose mesa redrock events helpers ) 2018- 
12-12 23:51:54Esten_Middles (phoenix tucson scottdale chandler brainburg
```

And i need only

```
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)
```

The number of characters may vary. How can i do it? PHP

Comment: What is the logic here?  Would there always be 4 lines of content before you want to trim?  Can you show other examples?

Comment: No, number of lines not constant it can be:
     [LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
     [LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)Evgeniy_Kytyzov (phoenix tucson 
scottdale chandler brainburg saintrose mesa redrock events helpers ) 2018
And etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string on the `(ONLINE...)` part, capturing the split strings and then removing the last item in the split array:

```
$input = '[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103)
[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733)
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)Evgeniy_Kytyzov (phoenix tucson 
scottdale chandler brainburg saintrose mesa redrock events helpers ) 2018- 
12-12 23:51:54Esten_Middles (phoenix tucson scottdale chandler brainburg 
saintrose mesa redrock central events helpers ) 2018-12-12 
23:52:31Steff_Kingston ';
$parts = preg_split('/(\(ONLINE:\s+\d+\))/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
array_pop($parts);
echo join('', $parts);
```

Output:

```
[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103) 
[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733) 
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32) 
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fMiTO)

**Update**

On the assumption that what you actually want to do is delete anything between `(ONLINE: nnn)` and the next `[LVL n]`, you can just use `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/(\(ONLINE:\s+\d+\)).*?(\[LVL|$)/s', "$1\n$2", $input);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/8Svui)

Comment: When you add a new `[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733)` at the end, your `array_pop` doesn't work as expected

Comment: @cbaconnier agreed. I was answering OPs question as it was. I've updated my answer with something more flexible that does "work" with the addition of other entries at the end as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `preg_split` with lookarounds:

```
$input = "[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103) "; // and the rest of your input
$parts = preg_split("/(?<=Juliette_Ortega\(ONLINE: 290\))(?=Evgeniy_Kytyzov)/", $input);
print_r($parts[0]);

[LVL 5] Steff_Kingston(ONLINE: 103)
[LVL 4] Oscar_Porsche(ONLINE: 733)
[LVL 3] Kenny_NewSide(ONLINE: 32)
[LVL 1] Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)
```

The regex logic says to split the string at any point where what *precedes* is `Juliette_Ortega(ONLINE: 290)` and what *follows* is `Evgeniy_Kytyzov`.  Then, we retain only the first component of the split, which is your expected output.